# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in C:\wamp\www\php test 11F\test.php on line 3

Tags: php

The variable $n is readed from a form:

```
<?php
$nume=$_POST['n']
for($i=1;$i<=n;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=n;$j++)
    {
      if($i==$j) $a[$i][$j]=0;
      else $a[$i][$j]=$i;
      echo $a[$i][$j]." ";
    }
  echo $a[$i][$j];
}
?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in C:\wamp\www\php
>   test 11F\test.php on line 3

What's the error, the problem?
It is my first project in php.

Comment: missing a semi-colon after `$nume=$_POST['n']`

Comment: missing `$` before `n` which should be `$nume`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$n = 20;
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
    {
      if($i==$j) 
          $a[$i][$j]=0;
      else 
        $a[$i][$j]=$i;
          echo $a[$i][$j]." ";
    }
}
?>
```

I fixed these issues,

1. n should be - `$n`
2. You are trying access value of `$a[$i][$j]` form outside the second loop - Then `$j` value equal to `$n+1` - but you can get only `1` to `$n`

Outside the two loops print the array this way then you can see what are the accessible keys

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. WHAT caused the OPs issue?

Comment: Thank you, I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

there is no semicolon after $_POST['n']. check below updated code

```
<?php
$nume=$_POST['n'];
for($i=1;$i<=$nume;$i++)
{
for($j=1;$j<=$nume;$j++)
{
  if($i==$j) $a[$i][$j]=0;
  else $a[$i][$j]=$i;
  echo $a[$i][$j]." ";
}
echo $a[$i][$j];
}
?>
```